# How set secure flag on all cookies for an API developed in .net Core 3.1 C#

Tags: c#, .net-core

I developed an API in .Net core 3.1 C# and I received this comment from security team:

"The secure flag should be set on all cookies that are used for transmitting sensitive data when accessing content over HTTPS."

In the Http Request I have this set-cookie

Set-Cookie = ARRAffinity=4a68cdswefr6babf170cab898f6db045c489b03fd905da71e885f1130cb67aab571939a

Is there a configuration to set the secure flag on all the cookies in ASP.Net Core 3.1?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the result of my research and the answer to this question:

According to this discussion there is no way to set the secure attribute for ARRAffinity cookie in .net code and as it is not a real security issue we can skip it.

Reference:
https://github.com/Azure/app-service-announcements-discussions/issues/26

We should use app.UseHttpsRedirection(); to ensure the API is only accessible via https.

And if the cookies are defined in the code, set the secure attribute manually

```
Response.Cookies.Add(
    new HttpCookie("key", "value")
    {
        Secure = true,
    });
```